# Select all options in multiple select with capybara-cucumber

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara

I have this html:

```
<select id="id_agents" style="" size="10" multiple="multiple" name="id_agents[]">
<option value="12">adama</option>
<option value="15">artica</option>
<option value="14">localhost</option>
<option value="8">localhost.localdomain</option>
<option value="13">test</option>
</select>
```

And I am trying with cucumber to select all values but it is not running. These are my tries:

```
When /^I select all in "(.*)"/ do |select_id|
    options = all(:xpath, "//select[@id='" + select_id + "']/option").click
    options.each do |option|
        option.click
    end
    #~ find(:xpath, "//select[@id='" + select_id + "']/option").each do |element|
        #~ element.click
    #~ end
    sleep(10)
end
```

Answer (score 8):

I was able to do the following:

```
select = page.find('select#select_id')
select.select 'Option 1'
select.select 'Option 2'
select.select 'Option 3'
select.unselect 'Option 1'
```

Answer (score 0):

I found....it is:

```
page.all(:xpath, "//select[@id='" + select_id + "']/option").each do |e|
        e.click
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same example so I hope it helps you

1) Senario:

```
    @create-product-backlog-with-multi-assign-to
    Scenario: Create a product backlog successfully
    Given I am on the new product backlog page
    #Then show me the page
    When I fill in a form with the following multiple values:
    |Project Title   |Project 1        |
    |Type            |Features         |
    |Title           |Product Backlog 8|
    |Priority        |Urgent           |
    # Product Backlog must have "State" is "Not Started" initially
    |State           |Not Started      |
    |Description     |description 8    |
    |Assign To       |developer,tester |
    |Estimated Hours | 48              |
    |Business Value  | 1               |
    |ROI             |0.02             |

    #|Attachment files|                 |
    # ROI is calculated from Business Value/Estimated Hours and this field is disable
    And I click on "Save" button
    Then I should be redirected to the product backlog index page
    #When I wait 5 seconds
    #When I select "All sprints" from "search_sprint_id"
    Then show me the page
    #When I wait 5 seconds

    # product backlog will assign to current user by default
    Then I should see a table with the following rows
    |ID|Title            |Priority|ROI  |State        |Assign To             |Estimated |Actions|
    |* |Product Backlog 8| Urgent |0.02 |Not Started  |admin,developer,tester|48        |*      |
```

- "Assign To" is select tag

2) Step definitions

```
  When(/^I fill in a form with the following multiple values:$/) do |table|
     expectations = table.raw
     expectations.each do |label, expected_value|
       field =  find_field("#{label}")

       case field.tag_name
       when 'select'
          expected_value.split(',').each do |value|
             step %(I select "#{value}" from "#{label}")
          end
       when 'checkbox','radio'
          step %(I check "#{label}") unless expected_value.nil?
       else
         step %(I fill in "#{label}" with "#{expected_value}")
      end
    end
 end
```

Comment: What if the option text contains `,`?

Comment: you can split it with comma and loop them same as in case of  'select'. It depends on your specific case so you can customize it properly to suit your purpose

Comment: then your solution cannot apply to generic cases. have to change the code case by case.